# What are target fixtures used for?

Tags: python, pytest, bdd, fixtures, pytest-bdd

```
@given("employees informations are added", target_fixture="information_db")
def ensure_employees_informations_added(): 
    return [_get_employee_information()]
```

My question is will the returned list be saved in "information_db" ? (I am new with working with pytest )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are using `pytest-bdd` plugin in additional to bare pytest.

The plugin's documentation can be found at https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-bdd

Long story short, yes. The returned list will be saved under `information_db` name.

The next clause can access it by putting the target fixture's name into a list of the function's arguments:

```
@given("check employee")
def check_employee(information_db): 
    assert information_db[0]['skill'] == 42
```